# I am unable to uninstall Angular-Cli on Ubuntu Server

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular-cli

I am unable to uninstall Angular in server on Ubuntu.

i tried the below commands

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
```

when i uninstall the angular , i am getting the error. find the screenshots for your reference.

[image]

when i run the node, npm and ng commands in the server,it is showing version but ng command not working. I have installed ng using this command sudo apt install ng-common successfully but it is showing same erro like ng is currently not installed. find the screenshot for your reference.

[image]

how can i uninstall angular in server?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's installed, the only thing you'll need to do is make sure that the `ng` bin is in your `PATH`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How can i remove angular complete in server

Comment: Try to delete ng like this: `rm -f /usr/bin/ng`

Comment: thanks for your support. I run the below command, it as uninstalled successfully.    sudo rm -f /usr/bin/ng   then npm uninstall -g @angular/cli